How can I build an object from a file path?
I'm working in JavaScript, and have an array of filepaths:
['root/folder1', 'root/folder1/folderA', 'root/folder1/folderA/folderi', 'root/folder1/folderB', 'root/folder2', ...]

and so on.  The filepaths are in order, so 'folder1' will always be listed before 'folder1/folderA', and so on.
I need to convert this to a tree structure, which is leaving me stumped.  I'm aiming for something like this (the next step will have files in each folder as well, so I need to prep for that):
allFolders = {
  root: {
    'files': [],
    'folders': {
      folder1: {
        'files': [],
        'folders': {
          folderA: {...},
          folderB: {...}
        }
      },
      folder2: {}
    }
  } 
}

although I'm open to any structure that works.  I need to be able to iterate over the final result to display a file tree like this:
root
  - folder1
    -- folderA
       --- folderi
    -- folderB
  - folder2

I don't really have any code to show because I haven't got as far as producing anything that's even remotely useful.

Please show us your attempts, even if they don't work.

creating a loop inside the loop might work. Is this for collecting data or creating a structure like that ?

Thanks - have been given links to related questions, so I'll check those out.
